# In iOS 11 and Xcode 9.0 beta3,can not use the instance method "pathForResource:ofType:" of NSBundle to get the path of file

Tags: ios11

In iOS 11 and Xcode 9.0 beta3
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SqueezeNet" ofType:@"mlmodel"],
I have already put the file into project，but the path is nil.

Comment: Select File in xcode and than select you project from Target Membership